# How to execute a code after the file is created?

Tags: visual-c++

I am having this problem. My `ShellExecute` works fine, the output is a PNG image file. The problem is this process take some time (seconds) for the file to be produced. Meanwhile, my `result` here has already executed but it produce error message because the PNG file from `ShellExecute` does not exist yet. How to make sure that the file is exist first, then after that `result` can execute.

```
    ShellExecute(0,                           
                 _T("open"),            
                 _T("c:\\convert.exe"), 
                 full,                  
                 0,                     
                 SW_HIDE);

    result  = ExecuteExternalProgramCompare(L"c.png", L"t.png");  // this line always gives error because the file c.png is not produce yet by shellexecute above.
```

update:
My attempt to convert to ShellexecuteEx.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};

info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
info.lpFile = _T("c:\\convert.exe");
info.lpParameters = full;
info.nShow = SW_HIDE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  This will allow you to get a handle on the called process, so that you can wait for the process to end.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};

info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
info.lpVerb = _T("open");
info.lpFile = _T("c:\\convert.exe");
info.lpParameters = full;
info.lpDirectory = NULL;
info.nShow = SW_HIDE;

if (ShellExecuteEx (&info))
{
   WaitForSingleObject (info.hProcess, INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: How to convert my parameters inside shellexecute to this? It seems to have different structure for passing the values?